# Dividing one DataTable into many

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datatable, dataset

I am trying to transfer rows from one `DataTable` to many other dynamically generated `DataTable`s. The parent `DataTable` contains data in following format:

```
ID  Name  Type
--------------
 1   ABC     0
 1   PQR     2
 2   XYZ     8
 2   QWE     7
 3   IOP     6
```

I want that the rows with same `ID` must be in one table. For example, above scenario will generate 3 tables. One containing rows with `ID = 1`, second one containing rows with `ID = 2` and third one containing rows with `ID = 3`. I am trying to achieve this using following code:

```
DataSet ResultantDataSet = new DataSet();
DataView dv = InputDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "ID";
int newID = -1;
DataTable dt = null;
foreach(DataRow dr in dv.ToTable().Rows) {
    if (newID != int.Parse(dr["ID"].ToString())) {
        newID = int.Parse(dr["ID"].ToString());
        if (dt != null) ResultantDataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
        dt = new DataTable();
    } else {
        dt.ImportRow(dr);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the `ResultantDataSet` contains tables with empty rows that have single unnamed column. What is going wrong?

Comment: Not to nitpick or anything but why would you want to do that? That sounds like a horrible form of denormalization.

Comment: @Zane actually I have a user control that accepts `DataSet`s and display them in a particular format. To convert it to that format I need to do this.

Comment: Okay well then your best bet to me sounds like inserting the unique ID's into a #Table and then loop through for each value and use a dynamic SQL Statment to insert to a table for each value. Sorry not sure I have time to write you a code example for how to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly add the columns ID, Name and Type to the new dt object, immediately after the dt = new DataTable() call? Maybe ImportRow does not automatically create columns, and if there are no existing columns it can't copy the values from the original row into new new rows of the new table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
        IEnumerable<DataTable> tables =
            table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(t => t.Field<int>("ID")).Select(t => t.CopyToDataTable());
```

Comment: If it works (I haven't tried) this would be a very elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks @Yohannes you are a lifesaver. :)

Comment: Was waiting to find out if this works before Upvoting as I am a database guy and an utter bafoon with application code.

Comment: @Zane it's vice-versa for me :D But I didn't expected a one line solution to this. This worked like a magic. :)